# Angular JS views not updating properly

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have the following action

**ng-click** in my view **->** which inturn calls a **jQuery ajax** function that displays jQuery Qtip **->** In the Qtip popup I have an **ng-click** on an element -> which performs a **$http post** and has some **callbacks to update $scope values**.

So all these things are happening properly. But the updates are not getting reflected in the view as per the changes made in the callback in the final stage.

I have a function for "ng-mousemove" in my view. So whenever I move my mouse, the updates in the view are getting reflected.

What am I doing wrong here? Is the because of transitioning between angular and non-angular? Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval) explains:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life-cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

So if you have a **jQuery code** like

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', function() {
  // do stuff
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: In my code, I have only ng-click that calls the angular function. I do **jQuery.qtip()** inside that angular function. That jQuery.qtip also does a **jQuery post internally** to get the content of Qtip. But the digest is already running when I try to do apply after the qtip() function is being called. What is the right place for **$apply**? Shouldn't that be called after the qtip is rendered?

Comment: An Angular nerd told me to use `if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();`

Comment: In addition, the safest way to call `$scope.$apply` is : `if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }`

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell angular Js something has changed with `$scope.$apply()`.

Here is a nice blog on why: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/10/more-angularjs-magic-to-supercharge-your-webapp.html#apply-digest-and-phase